# How to attach source code of libraries downloaded with ivy

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I use ivy with the ivy eclipse plugin to download dependencies. Works great. But how can I attach the source code for those libraries, in order to step into these libraries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried attaching the source configurations?

```
<dependencies defaultconfmapping="*->default,sources">
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything. Does this actually work for you? Or is it just an idea?

Comment: Now it works for me as well. I had to do 'resolve' via menu. Strange, I thought it does that whenever one edits the ivy.xml ... anyway. Thanx for the help

Comment: FYI, there's an IvyDE console to get more information about what IvyDE is doing.  Open the regular Eclipse console, and there's a dropdown menu giving you a list of console types.  IvyDE should be in there, and if you switch to it, you'll get another menu to change the log level.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  "ivy -verbose" shows the 'sources' being added to every fetch, and the Ivy cache shows configurations with 'sources', but I see no sources.  Ivy 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [ant task](http://code.google.com/p/ivy-eclipse/) that will modify the .classpath file to reference the source attachments.

Answer (score 2):

I use the IvyDE plugin, and it seems to automatically download and attach sources.  I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Apache IvyDE 2.2.0.  I didn't have to do anything special in my ivy.xml file or in my Ant build: it just works.

There is a preferences page that might relate to this. For me, it's Window > Preferences > Ivy > Source/Javadoc Mapping:

[image]

Those settings affect your entire workspace.