# How to get sources for Grails dependencies

Tags: grails, ivy

How can I get Ivy to download the sources for dependencies from within Grails?

I tried editing all the ivy.xml files I could find as [per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083860/source-code-of-libraries-downloaded-with-ivy), but no luck.

```
~/.grails/1.3.4/projects/workspace-sts/integration-files/ivy.xml
/c/grails-1.3.4/src/grails/ant/ivy.xml
```

I've been reading the grails source, and can't find any way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Grails Eclipse Scripts Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/eclipse-scripts)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 7 / SpringSource Tool Suite  2.3.3.CI-R5572-B51 / Grails 1.3.4 without heavy modification.

For example, the "eclipse_workspace_settings.epf" file it generates has "C:\adsf\asdf" paths, whereas eclipse seems to need "C\:/asdf/asdf" style paths for the file to be accepted.

It did get me most of the way there though.

Comment: Grails developers says that there would be more flexible dependency management starting from 1.3.5 or 1.4.0.
But till that happened the only solution is to use Eclipse Scripts Plugin - fully or to create own plugin based on it.

Comment: That's because this kind of plugin is developped once and hardly maintained. Once the integration on the IDE side is more solid you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 11):

I just use:

```
grails refresh-dependencies --include-source
```